# Functionality similar to CoreNLP's OpenIE on spaCy

Tags: tuples, rdf, spacy, information-extraction

I like spaCy. However, I want functionality like that of CoreNLP's [OpenIE](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/openie.html), wherein I get the Subject, Verb & Predicate out-of-the-box. What are my options? Should I use both the frameworks?

Answer (score 2):

Try AllenNLP's pretrained OpenIE model: https://demo.allennlp.org/open-information-extraction. (Note: AllenNLP uses spaCy)